# Unable to extend VPC CIDR range

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-vpc, cidr

I have created a default VPC via the console and next thing is to add a CIDR range to this VPC, one that starts from `192.168.0.0`, but I have found out that if my previous CIDR range for the VPC is `172.31.0.0/16` it is not possible to add the new CIDR range I wanted.

Can someone help me with that and address me to the correct documentation regarding this issue?

The only solution I found was to make another VPC with the wanted CIDR range from the beginning.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are rules regarding which CIDR blocks you can use.

As you're using a class B address range (CIDR within the `172.16.0.0/12` range) you're restricted to using a address range from one of the following:

- Any other CIDR from the 172.16.0.0/12 range that's not restricted.
- Any publicly routable IPv4 CIDR block (non-RFC 1918), or a CIDR block from the 100.64.0.0/10 range.

Take a look at the [full suite of rules for additional subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-resize) to help you decide.

Comment: Ok, will look into it. Additionally,can I decide on the CIDR range of my default VPC I upon creation or is it always 172.31.0.0/16?

Comment: The default VPC in all regions is create as `172.31.0.0/16`, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html